# Getting FedEx retail rates

Tags: c#, fedex

We currently use the FedEx web services to shop rate requests.  But we have to put in our account / meter number which affects the rates returned to the system.

```
request.ClientDetail = new ClientDetail();
request.ClientDetail.AccountNumber = options.AccountNumber;
request.ClientDetail.MeterNumber = options.MeterNumber;
```

If we exclude these values, the requests fail.  But we have customers going to FedEx.com and shopping rates for themselves.  When they do this, the account they request under appears to be some sort of retail account.  So our rates never match up.  Is there a way to get an account number / meter number that more closely matches the retail rates customers would get when they visit the FedEx website?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @TyleH It is C#, but really the problem is language agnostic.

Comment: That may be so but there are 4 orders of magnitude more watchers of [tag:C#] than of [tag:fedex], and you no doubt are not interested in a solution using every language under the sun. At any rate, after reading the question closely, this sounds more like something you should be asking FedEx, not random users online. I would imagine FedEx specifically *intends* for a business rate to differ from a consumer/retail rate. User education may be the solution, especially if the rates they're seeing are higher than your business rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, when you sign up with Fedex, you have to provide a company account that immediately is different than the rates published on the FedEx.com website.  Tech support let me know that there is no way to get the retail rates.